# Something wrong with fileDependencies.R(file) when deploying shinydashboard

Tags: r, shiny

I wrote a shinyapp based on shinydashboard, and when I deployed it to shinyapps.io, it has warning messages say:

1: In fileDependencies.R(file) :
Failed to parse C:/Users/feiwuu/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp42sbBV/file4dc4f7a3a5/server.R ; dependencies in this file will not be discovered.
2: In fileDependencies.R(file) :
Failed to parse C:/Users/feiwuu/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp42sbBV/file4dc4f7a3a5/ui.R ; dependencies in this file will not be discovered.

Did anyone knows what's wrong when this situation happens?
Looking forward to your answer. THX

Answer (score 0):

Try to [change encoding](https://github.com/rstudio/rsconnect/issues/123#issuecomment-260039648) before deployment.

```
tmp.enc <- options()$encoding
options(encoding = "UTF-8")
deployApp()
options(encoding = tmp.enc)
```