# The application failed to start. Contact the author for more information

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps, jsonlite

I just tried to deploy my first shiny app. The first error I got was:

```
Warning messages:
1: In fileDependencies.R(file) :
  Failed to parse C:/Users/kinde/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpu2zAya/filef7c613e1e15/app.R ; dependencies in this file will not be discovered.
2: Error detecting locale: Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote, : unvollständige letzte Zeile von readTableHeader in 'raw' gefunden
 (Using default: en_US)
```

I found out that it might have been an encoding issue so I tried:

```
tmp.enc <- options()$encoding
options(encoding = "UTF-8")
library(rsconnect)
rsconnect::deployApp('pathToFolder')
```

(This is what I found here: [Something wrong with fileDependencies.R(file) when deploying shinydashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52809151/something-wrong-with-filedependencies-rfile-when-deploying-shinydashboard))

Now I only get the second error(translated):

```
Warning message:
Error detecting locale: Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote, : incomplete final line found by readTableHeader in 'raw' gefunden
 (Using default: en_US)
```

The only data that I am using is with the following:

```
url <- "https://covid19-dashboard.ages.at/data/JsonData.json"
df <- jsonlite::fromJSON(txt = url)
```

How do I solve this?